# Deletion of a Q

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, specific-question, deleted-questions

I have posted a [reasonable Q](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102136/do-the-rules-imply-i-am-a-perception-savant?noredirect=1#102141), in my opinion: one that presents a line of reasoning, backed by rules, and asks for validation. However, I would like it to be removed. It's currently on hold.

The reason for removal is, I'm not willing to improve this Q to the standards of the Stack. As I have said above, I believe it is already reasonable. I am not willing to adjust to a discrepancy between me and the Stack in terms of question asking *for this particular case*, because I'm already aware of the uphill climb that particular resistance and refining is going to take.

In its current form, it is what the Stack considers to be low quality. Given the Q is on hold as opinion-based, the two answers that have been given must not be factually based but rather are simply opinions. Currently, they have a low upvote score (3 on one, 1 on the other).

It seems like a prime candidate for deletion, so, my Q here is simply, may the linked Q be deleted?

Comment: For future reference, asking only for people's judgement about whether something is good cheese or bad cheese is likely to be closed as primarily opinion based, for what I hope are obvious reasons. There's nothing wrong with the setup of the question, just with the actual question that it uses that setup to ask.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sure, I've deleted it. Enjoy.

Keep in mind that we don't always delete questions at the OP's request - there's a reason the system doesn't allow that after there's upvoted answers. Maybe you've given up on a question but it's not yours any more, it's the community's.

But, in this case, it was still closed and highly downvoted, and there were only 2 low voted answers both of which were basically opinion, so IMO it fit the "OK to delete" criteria.

Note another recent question that requested deletion didn't get deleted - [How will this much GP impact our game?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/102049/how-will-this-much-gp-impact-our-game) - because even though it's closed it has a lot more upvoted, activity, and an accepted answer.  So just in case you're wondering what the line is for us to accept a self-delete request, it's somewhere between those two.